# Inserting a new column in a HTML table using javascript

Tags: javascript, object

i'm trying to add a button to a dynamically created table but I can't get the insertCell() method to skip the first row (these are the table headers).. Can anyone please advise me where i'm going wrong. Thanks..

Also any help on improving this code would be appreciated as I've only just started learning JavaScript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
  <title>Client Side Shopping Basket</title>
  <meta name="author" content="Justin">
  <link href="basket.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">
    <header id="title">
        <h1>Products</h1>
    </header>
    <div class="output">
        <table border="1" id="productTable">
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Description</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Gender</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <br /><br />
    <header id="title">
        <h1>Shopping Basket</h1>
    </header>
    <div id="basket">
        <table border="1">
            <tr class="netcost">
                <td class="light">Net Total:</td>
                <td colspan="2" class="light"></td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
                <td>&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="totalcost">
                <td class="light">Total:</td>
                <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
                <td colspan="2"><span class="thick">£225.45</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="checkout">
                <td colspan="5" class="checkout"><button id="submitbtn">Checkout Now!</button></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<p id="test"></p>

<script>
var productList = []; //where product objects are to be held
var basket = [];
var objectNames = [];
var obj;
//constructor
function Product(name, description, quantity, price, gender) 
{ 
    obj = this; // a reference to this object

    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.price = price.toFixed(2);
    this.gender = gender;
    this.getName = function() {
        return this.name
    };
    this.getPrice = function() {
        return '\u00A3' + this.price;
    };
};

//instantiate new products 
var shorts = new Product('Shorts', 'Stone Wash Demin Shorts', 20, 25.90, 'F');
var bag = new Product('Bag', 'Leather Shoulder Bag', 4, 50.45, 'F');
var blouse = new Product('Blouse', 'Vintage Blue Silk Polka Dot Blouse', 8, 45.99, 'F');
var boots = new Product('Boots', 'Soft Leather Brown Ankle Boots', 3, 65.35, 'F');
var belts = new Product('Belts', 'Woven Finish Fashion Belt', 15, 21.99, 'F');
var shirt = new Product('Shirt', 'Jacquard Pattern Wrangler Western Shirt', 19, 34.87, 'M');
var shoes = new Product('Shoes', 'Suede Ankle Boots', 6, 55.00, 'M');
var trousers = new Product('Trousers', 'Izod Peach Chinos', 23, 31.75, 'M');
var belt = new Product('Belt', 'Suede Casual Belt', 4, 22.98, 'M');
var hat = new Product('Hat', 'Trilby Style Brown Woven Fix', 2, 67.80, 'M');

//add objects to an array
productList.push(shorts, bag, blouse, boots, belts, shirt, shoes, trousers, belt, hat);

function appendRow(productTable) {
    var tbl = document.getElementById('productTable'); // reference to table
    var cellCount = tbl.rows[0].cells.length; // counts the cells in first row of table
    var row = tbl.insertRow(1); // inserts a row
    var counter;
    for (var counter=0; counter < countCells; ++counter) { // iterate through table headers 
    };
};
//print product list
function createTable(products) {   // passes in the product list

    var tbl = document.getElementById('productTable'); // reference to the table to add rows to

    for (var i=0; i < products.length; i++) { // index the productsList (iterate through 0-9)

        var myProduct = products[i]; // keep a reference to each individual product - shorts, bag, blouse, etc...
        var row = tbl.insertRow(tbl.rows.length); // create a row element to append cells to
        var myProperties = ['name', 'description', 'quantity', 'price', 'gender']; //store the property names of the products, references to the object data

        var objectName = products[i].name.toLowerCase(); //lower-case the name for object name
        objectNames[i] = objectName; // add them to an array ????

        for (var j=0; j < myProperties.length; j++) // for each property in myProperties [0-4]
        {   
            var cell = document.createElement('td'); //create table cell element
            var data = myProduct[myProperties[j]]; // store property values of products
            var node = document.createTextNode(data); //add the data to a text node 
            cell.appendChild(node); // append text node to table cell
            row.appendChild(cell); // add to end of the row
        }

        var newCell = tbl.rows[i].insertCell(tbl.rows[i].cells.length); // insert new cell at end of each row

        function createBtn() {
        //create button
            var btn = document.createElement('input'); 
            btn.type = 'button';
            btn.value = 'Add';
            btn.name = objectNames[i];
            btn.onclick = function() {alert(objectNames);};
            return btn;
        };

        newCell.appendChild(createBtn()); // add button to cell
        tbl.appendChild(row); // add new row to table
    }
};

createTable(productList); // pass in productList Array

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Use proper mark up put the header in a thead element and the content rows in a tbody element. Than you can reference the rows

Comment: Is your row index of by one? `tbl.rows[i]` should be `tbl.rows[i+1]`

Comment: @epascarello Please elaborate

Comment: @Halcyon No that does not work

Comment: And if you replace `tbl.rows[i]` by `row`?

Comment: @epascarello Do you mean I append the newCell to the tbody element

Comment: @Halcyon var newCell = tbl.rows[i+1].insertCell(tbl.rows[i+1].cells.length); This works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple solution without modifying much of your code...

Change the way how you create newCell (line 122). Replace with the following line:

```
    *var newCell = tbl.rows[i+1].insertCell(tbl.rows[i+1].cells.length); // insert new cell at end of each row*
```